# Viewpager OutofMemory on Fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting a strange OutOfMemoryError when using a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

The fragments have just a root element, and the Activity is very basic, as I have tried to strip it down to the bare bones to try and figure out where it is occuring.

It seems to happen after the `onCreateView()` in the Fragment, but can't seem to find the culprit.

Thanks very much for your help.

**Activity**

```
public class Activity_Content_Dialog extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SlideshowAdapter _slideShowAdapter;
    private ViewPager _viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_dialog);

        _slideShowAdapter = new SlideshowAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

       _viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
       _viewPager.setAdapter(_slideShowAdapter);
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_dialog_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
 public class Fragment_Empty extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View  view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_frag,container);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

**Pager Adapter**

```
public class SlideshowAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SlideshowAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
           super(fm);
    }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new Fragment_Empty();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

}
```

**Finally, here is the error message**

```
10-29 10:51:26.605  27188-27188/? E/art? Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 22227766 byte allocation with 14873872 free bytes and 14MB until OOM"
10-29 10:51:26.605  27188-27188/? E/AndroidRuntime? Error reporting crash
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 22227766 byte allocation with 14873872 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
            at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
            at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
            at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
            at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
            at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
            at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
            at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
            at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
            at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
            at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
            at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:335)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: Hey, have you managed to solve this problem or at least have a clue?

Comment: This won't be the most helpful answer, but I was getting OOM errors due to caching numerous bitmaps in memory. I ended up using a 3rd party library called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) which deals with resourcing pooling, memory and caching all for you. There are examples of how to use this on their github page.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try and if I come up with any other solutions I will post it here either.

Comment: I am getting this error. Nothing more to add, just that I detest modern Android more than I can say.

Comment: Found the cause. Don't pass 'container' to the inflate() call in onCreateView(), pass null instead. Good old Android, it's been a steaming pile of time-wasting crap for 8 years and counting.

Answer (score 0):

Change this section:

```
 View  view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_frag,container);
```

to:

```
 View  view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_frag,container,false);
```